# launch python file from an xml file

Tags: python, xml

I was wondering if in an xml file I could launch a python file and based on what python returns run different parts of the xml code.

Something like

IN THE XML FILE:

- run the python file
- if the file retuns A, run the A code of this XML file
- else run the B code of this XML file

thanks!

Comment: You have it backwards, you open the xml from python, read it and do stuff based on what it says. The answer to your question is then: yes, it is possible. Try it and ask when you find a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An XML file can't run a python script since XML is a descriptive language used to represent data.

However you can do the opposite, that's to say, use python to read the XML file and do something.

By the way when you say "run the A code of this XML file", i'm not sure you're doing it right, since XML is not supposed to contain "active code".

Comment: thanks,I imagined it was the wrong way to do it but I wanted to see if it was possible.

Comment: There are of course XML vocabularies used to contain active code: a common example is an Ant script, and you can launch Python applications from an Ant script. But that's a feature of Ant, not of XML.